# How to read gmon.out?

Tags: c++, gcc, windows-7, profile

How do I read gmon.out in Windows? Windows can't so much as open the file, so `gmon.out options` doesn't quite work in the command-line window.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[gprof](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/courses/programming/gprof.html) is the tool that reads a `gmon.out` file and displays information from it.

Comment: You need to give gprof the executable filename. E.g. `gprof <executable-filename> gmon.out  >output.txt`   Then open output.txt using any editor. See the manual: http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/gprof/